# Subdividing mesh causing weird bulging

Tags: shaders, subdivision-surface

[image] Bulging issue happens whether or not I am using the Subdivision modifier or subdividing it manually and removing Bevels doesn't help as well. The area in in question is CURVED.

Shading with Autosmoothing is turned on and tried putting in bigger angles which didnt help. Normals are facing the right way aswell.

I think im missing a simple fix, TIA :)

Comment: you must have subdivided it with right click > Subdivide and it has added edge loops along existing edge loops which has made them sharper, while applying a Subdivision Surface modifier would have avoided the problem. Also, why did you subdivide?

Comment: I wanted subdiv to add more details in that area, While Subdivision modifier level 1 kinda makes it unnoticable other levels bring the bulging back, but I guess that will be my makeshift fix for now, Thank you! @moonboots

Comment: you can try a Ctrl E > Un-Subdivide if you want to remove edges

Comment: can you share the blend file with inside the only mesh with the problem?

Comment: well i dont have the mesh anymore in that state as i applied subdiv level 1 which made it unnoticable but i think unsubdiving it and then adding supporting loops wouldve helped the cause